# How do I dynamically update a <p> element when a date is selected from an input type="date"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a paragraph element that I'd like to dynamically update to display whatever the date selected from my input type="date" element is:

```html
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date" required>

<p id='testVariable3'></p>
```

So far I've tried this, but it doesn't update:

```html
<div>
  <h4 style="padding: 5px">Select a date</h4>
</div>

<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date" required />

<script>
  var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
  document.getElementById("datepicker").min = currentDate;
</script>

<p id="testVariable1"></p>
<p id="testVariable2"></p>
<p id="testVariable3"></p>

<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>

<script>
  const hotdeskLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".test a");
  var allBookings = "{{all-bookings}}";
  var decodedBookings = allBookings.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');

  const test1 = document.getElementById("testVariable1");
  const workspaceAttributes = JSON.parse(decodedBookings).map(
    (decodedBookings) => decodedBookings.workspace
  );
  test1.textContent = workspaceAttributes;

  const test2 = document.getElementById("testVariable2");
  const dateAttributes = JSON.parse(decodedBookings).map(
    (decodedBookings) => decodedBookings.date
  );
  test2.textContent = dateAttributes;

  const datepicker = document.getElementById("datepicker");
  const test3 = document.getElementById("testVariable3");

  datepicker.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    const selectedDate1 = datepicker.value;
    test3.textContent = selectedDate;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you give us the whole code HTML+JS, maybe you just place the script in the `<head>` tag instead of the bottom before `</body>`?

Comment: Your code is generally correct and should be working, assuming that the JavaScript code is run after the HTML elements have been loaded. Can you test that your script can access your element by logging that element to console with `console.log(datepicker)`

Comment: @XMehdi01 sure, I've just updated the code to show exactly how it is.

Comment: Where is the element that `const hotdeskLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.test a');` is supposed to select?

Comment: `allBookings` is the string `"{{all-bookings}}"`; why do you need to replace HTML quote entities? In addition, that is not JSON, so you cannot parse it. Did you redact something? Perhaps you were intending to load data or something?

Comment: Can someone flag to close as "caused by typo"? (I had already flagged as "needs debugging details" and so can't flag again.)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes is there a way for me to do that? Apologies for time wasting

Comment: Yes. Underneath your question, there should be a row of five buttons, "Share Edit Close Delete Flag". Click "Close", then "A community-specific reason" (second option), then "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" (fourth option), and then click the big "Vote to close" button at the bottom.

Comment: If you feel that this question and the answers are almost entirely useless to most people, you _can_ **delete** it if you feel to. However, I believe there is some useful info: (1) The code that actually does the part you want does work, if someone wants that. (2) The fact that the `change` event will only be emitted when all the components of the date are present. (3) The oft-stated fact that the script must come after the elements it works with (discounting scripts that work with dynamiclly-added elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a small typo at the bottom of your script. This is your code:

```
datepicker.addEventListener('change',  function(event) {
const selectedDate1 = datepicker.value;
test3.textContent = selectedDate;
```

You declared `selectedDate1` in your event listener function and then tried to assign `selectedDate` to `test3.textContent`

See if changing this typo can fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much Erhan, this was the issue. Silly me.

Comment: It happens to all of us. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works! You just have to make sure that in the HTML code, you're loading the script *after* you create the `input` and `p` elements in the body.

Something like this:

```html
<body>
    <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date" required>
    <p id='dynamicDate'></p>

    <script>
        const datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker');
        const test = document.getElementById('dynamicDate');

        datepicker.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        const selectedDate = datepicker.value;
        test.textContent = selectedDate;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

To do this in your code, you can do it like this:

```html
<div>
    <h4 style="padding: 5px; ">Select a date</h4>
</div>

<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="date" required>

<script>
    var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    document.getElementById("datepicker").min = currentDate;
</script>

<p id='testVariable1'></p>
<p id='testVariable2'></p>
<p id='testVariable3'></p>

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>

<script>
    // Moved this code out of the second script tag
    const datepicker = document.getElementById('datepicker');
    const test3 = document.getElementById('testVariable3');

    datepicker.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        const selectedDate = datepicker.value;
        test3.textContent = selectedDate;
    });
</script>

<script>
    const hotdeskLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.test a');
    var allBookings = '{{all-bookings}}';
    var decodedBookings = allBookings.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');

    const test1 = document.getElementById('testVariable1');
    const workspaceAttributes = JSON.parse(decodedBookings).map((decodedBookings) => decodedBookings.workspace);
    test1.textContent = workspaceAttributes;
    const test2 = document.getElementById('testVariable2');
    const dateAttributes = JSON.parse(decodedBookings).map((decodedBookings) =>
        decodedBookings.date);
    test2.textContent = dateAttributes;

    // Originally here
</script>
```

All I've done here is separated the second script tag into 2 so that it runs separately! *(Also a small typo!)*

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Boris, I've updated my code with exactly how it looks in my project, can you see anything wrong there?

Comment: Should the date be showing up after the button is clicked? or immediately when the date is changed?

Comment: Immediately when the date is changed, if that's possible

Comment: I've just edited my answer, hope it helped!

Comment: Moving that section of the script into its own block changes nothing: it did and still does run after the elements are created. You also seem to have fixed the `selectedDate1`/`selectedDate` naming mismatch without mentioning it at all, which might be the actual issue.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply Boris, turns out there was a slight typo in the original code (selectedDate/selectedDate1)

Comment: I tried fixing that issue, however, it made no difference on my end. Separating the scripts into different tags fixed the issue for me. Is there a chance that the browser could be running a different version of HTML/JS and that could be the reason I needed to separate it?

Comment: No, it's not your browser. It's because the code that was above it has a fatal error, so the datepicker code never actually runs when they're in the same block. The JSON parse fails due to invalid input and that's that for that block. I kinda mentioned it in [a comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76582477/how-do-i-dynamically-update-a-p-element-when-a-date-is-selected-from-an-input?noredirect=1#comment135025268_76582477).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. However, it's important to know that the "change" listener will only be triggered after filling out all of the components of the date (e.g. month, year, and day).

[image]